# unable to rotate only one view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

i am using XCode 4.2 (with storyboards)

I am trying to rotate only one of the views (and not all the views) but it doesn t seem to be working... either non of the views get rotated or all of them

I have checked all the supported views in the summary , and in info I made sure that the application "supported interface orientations" are all there

in the class that is related to the view I wrote the function to rotate this specific view :

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutoRotateToInterfactOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return(interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown||
interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||
interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||
interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
}
```

and still it does not rotate when I rotate the screen ... any clue ?

Comment: Are you sure about those "not equal" operators? Shouldn't you use "==" or simply return YES?

Comment: I tried the "YES" and tried the ==... none are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method can be reduced to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfactOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation; {
  return YES;
}
```

What you want to do is have the device support orientations in ***all*** of the orientations you want, and then in the specific view's, use the above method to allow which orientations you want for that view. So for example, if you wanted only landscape modes for a particular view, you would use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfactOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation; {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

In `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` you have to return all the orientations that you want to support.

So if you want your app works just in portrait this is the code to use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

If you want to support all possible orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return YES;
    }
```